# Amazon Linux 2 OpenSSL Wrong Singature Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, python, openssl, amazon-linux-2

I'm coding a discord bot in python. Whenever I try to connect to a specific site, on my EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2, the script returns the following error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientConnectorSSLError: Cannot connect to host secure.site.here:443 ssl:None [[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1076)]
```

(actual url snipped.)

The bot itself is dockerized, running `python:3.7.4-slim-buster`. The error is not present when built with image `python:3.7.4-slim-stretch`.

I've also tested the same script built with base image `-buster` on MacOS and also a GCP Compute Engine instance, both are error free.

What am I missing? Any tips welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, without your sharing the name of the site which is presenting the error, is that it does not support TLSv1.2, and so OpenSSL isn't able to negotiate a connection.  Debian [disabled support for TLSv1.1 and earlier in OpenSSL as of the Buster release](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2017/08/msg00004.html), although there are suggestions that [it can be re-enabled on a per-application basis](https://bugs.python.org/issue31453) if you are so inclined.